# Permalinks contain unwanted space resulting in broken links

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, permalinks

I have just over 8k products listed on my wordpress site using WooCommerce.

Some product links work fine, vast majority for some reason have an unwanted space and - though ( -) resulting in 404, when i edit the link to remove these 2 characters the link becomes functional again.

The link appears like this inside wordpress editor-

[www.mydomain.com/product/](http://www.mydomain.com/product/) -randomproduct

On the frontend, the link appears as this:

Www.mydomain.com/product/%20randomproduct

I'm wondering if theres a way for me to bulk edit all the bad links to remove the 2 problem characters and fix my links.

Thanks for any help received.

Comment: Welcome to the portal Ali22 ! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can check how the site_url is stored in the wp_options table - make sure there is not a space after the url.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i checked and theres no space after the url. I would say this doesnt effect all my products, just the vast majority. Hope i dont have to manually correct all the links

Comment: You might try to add a filter to the url - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_type_link/ - this will enable you to debug the string being used and to replace spaces with nothing - for exampling using str_replace